# Getting the ID if i know the specific span text

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

my brain crashed.

I'm trying to get the ID of a span if specific text matches using BeautifulSoup, this because i need a number from the ID but the ID changes every time when searching for a new product but the product (CORRECT). Purpose of this is because when i have the number, 11 in this case, i can add it in another part of the code to scrape the information i need.

Example:

```
<span id="random-text-10-random-again">IGNORE</span>, 
<span id="random-text-11-random-again">CORRECT</span>,
<span id="random-text-12-random-again">IGNORE</span>
```

Been reading documentation but i never seem to get right or not even remotely close. I'm aware how to pull the text (CORRECT) if i know the ID but not reversed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find_all() span items with required text and then get the `id` attribute and `split()` the attribute value with `-`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''<span id="random-text-10-random-again">IGNORE</span> 
<span id="random-text-11-random-again">CORRECT</span>
<span id="random-text-12-random-again">IGNORE</span>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
for item in soup.find_all('span',text='CORRECT'):
    print(item['id'].split('-')[2])
```

It will print:

```
11
```

Comment: That's exactly what i was looking for. Thank you so much. I went straight away to play with those lines and have now implemented it. once again, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use `:contains` to target the innerText by a specified value. Available for bs4 4.7.1+

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<span id="random-text-10-random-again">IGNORE</span>, 
<span id="random-text-11-random-again">CORRECT</span>,
<span id="random-text-12-random-again">IGNORE</span>'''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
target = soup.select_one('span:contains("CORRECT")[id]')
if target is None:
    print("Not found")
else:
    print(target['id'].split('-')[2])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the input. Any lessons are highly valuable!